# What were the names of the spy rings besides Culper during the Revolutionary War?

Tags: american-revolution, espionage

I want to know the names of spy rings beyond the Culper spy ring, that operated during the American Revolutionary War.  Beyond just the name, it would be helpful to know where the spies operated as well (if such information is available). Providing outside sources is a big plus, but not necessary.

The names I am looking for are specific the names of the *rings of spies,* not the individual spies.  I have seen this information on a website before but I cannot locate it again.

Comment: [google reveals Mt. Vernon](http://www.mountvernon.org/george-washington/the-revolutionary-war/spying-and-espionage/american-spies-of-the-revolution/)

Comment: That isn't what I'm looking for, but thank you anyway

Comment: nice try, British informant :)

Comment: I'm not, I swear! In fact, I'm a loyal doctor of the Continental Army. @user69715

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beside Culper, you may be thinking of the [Clark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Clark_(spy)) Ring in Philadelphia, and the [Mersereau](http://founders.archives.gov/documents/Washington/03-05-02-0253) Ring of Staten Island, both of which are mentioned on page 4 of

[Covert operations and the emergence of the modern American presidency, 1920-1960](https://books.google.com/books?id=4H0fAQAAMAAJ&q=revolutionary%20war%20espionage%20ring%20clark%20philadelphia&dq=revolutionary%20war%20espionage%20ring%20clark%20philadelphia&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjN_6qG_-TPAhXDMj4KHT0nAccQ6AEISDAH)
by John J Carter

> ...espionage networks like the Culper Ring, which also engaged in
>   disinformation activities. In Philadelphia the Clark Ring was
>   operationally active from the early stages of the War, as was the
>   Mersereau Ring in the ...

A search through google books lists several other sources.

A web page for the [CIA](https://www.cia.gov/library/center-for-the-study-of-intelligence/csi-publications/books-and-monographs/the-founding-fathers-of-american-intelligence/art-1.html) has quite a bit of info as well.